# Detecting Hand touch event on iPad screen

Tags: ios, ipad, events, lua, coronasdk

As part of a children's application I am trying to detect a hand print on an ipad screen.  I can detect touches with the touch events but ultimately the hand is going to be 1 large touch event.  I am trying to detect the size and x,y position of the hand.  Any ideas on whether this is even possible?

The other part of this is I am using corona sdk/lua to develop.  Is the solution (if there is one) still going to be feasible, or should I look at changing to native code?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how practical this will be in native code. It sound like you could enable multi touch and on touch events you would get multiple locations. See the Multitouch sample app.

If you're on a Mac, open Finder and go to /Applications/CoronaSDK/SampleCode/Interface/ and there are three sample projects in there that involve multitouch. If you're on Windows it's C:\Program Files (x86)\CoronaSDK\SampleCode (I think).

Comment: Thanks Rob...when you say "see the Multitouch sample app" what app are you referring to?

Comment: We include around 100 small sample apps with your Corona SDK install. The path to those files is listed above depending if your on a Mac or PC. Full source code is included.

Comment: Thanks Rob!  Do you know is it possible to detect the area covered using Corona?